# Relationships in Django Admin

Tags: django-models, django-admin, many-to-many

I get really confused with many-to-many database relationships, so can some one please clarify how I would achieve this?

I need a table of "Tags" (as in tag words) and a table for "Entries", such at many "Entries" could correspond to many Tag words.

Right now I have my models like this:

```
# models.py
class Tags(models.Model):
    tag         = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    entry       = models.ManyToManyField(Entry)

class Entry(models.Model):
    entry       = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
```

Now I'm confused, how would I setup my admin.py so I could then add tags when I create a new entry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is using the `through` feature of models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag         = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    entry       = models.ManyToManyField(Entry, through='TaggedEntries')

class Entry(models.Model):
    entry       = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()

class TaggedEntries(models.Model):
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
```

and now use that model in your admin:

```
class TagsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TaggedEntries
    extra = 1

class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (TagsInline, )

admin.site.register(Entry, EntryAdmin)
admin.site.register(Tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need something along the lines of:

```
# admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from models import *

class TagsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Tag
    extra = 1

class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (TagsInline, )

admin.site.register(Entry, EntryAdmin)
admin.site.register(Tag)
```

(Note, this code was written in a browser!)

Comment: that's what I had actually, and I kept getting:
Exception: <class 'testProject.entries.models.Tags'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'testProject.entries.models.entry'>